# How to open ListPreference immediately while opening activity?

Tags: android, preferences, preferenceactivity, listpreference

I have created an application with two screens, MainActivity - screen with buttons, and PrefActivity - settings screen. In PrefActivity I have ListPreference. How to open ListPreference immediately while PrefActivity is opening?

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution ?